# What is PG pub issue notifcation means?

Tags: patent-applications

My patent transaction history is below. What does PG-Pub issue notification means? Does it mean my patent is approved and it is visible to public?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No and Yes**

It is not an indication that it is approved but it is an indication that the application is about to be published for the public to see. Note that a few actions below you see that a non-final rejection was mailed. There are a few steps after a rejection before you get a patent.

The information you posted is from one of the tabs in Public PAIR that gives a sometimes cryptic note of actions on your case, not all of which are of any substance. Another nearby tab will bring up the file history and you can see the entire detailed back-and-forth between you and the office, including your rejection.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I could see some of my claims have few sentences that collides with another patent.